# How do I insert text into the datePicker?

Tags: java, android, xml, datepicker

I need to insert text into the native Android `DatePicker`. How do I do this?

Here is my layout code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="700px"
    android:layout_height="300px"
    android:background="@drawable/time_format_24"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TableRow>
        <!-- define a TimePicker module -->
        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_width="420px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:endYear="2200"
            android:spinnersShown="true"
            android:startYear="2010"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.picker" />
        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.picker"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The final effect to be achieved is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom date piker library to do this using this library you can do any type of custom layout for a single date.

Library link: https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView

Note: you can not change the custom single date layout in `DatePicker`